# Is there any way to change the value of fields whose type is 'table' in runtime (with ajax or etc.) on Laravel Backpack CRUD?

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

In Laravel Backpack CRUD I want to change the current value of a field whose type is 'table' (I save its content as JSON) after changing an onther field. So is there any way to do this?

For example:
after changing some radio buttons I want to change the content of the 'table' field based on the radio's value.

Comment: yes it's possiable

Comment: @AndySong What is your opinion about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible. The easiest way to do this, in my opinion, would be to:

- [create a new field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#creating-a-custom-field-type) starting from the `radio` or `checkbox` or whatever field type you would like to be the toggle;
- use that field type instead of the original field type, in your form;
- inside the custom field type, inside the JavaScript, include the logic you want that would customize the `table` field;